# Having problems when posting large JSON data from one page to another page while using client side javascript

Tags: javascript, json, post

I have a webpage which is built using javascript, where the user can upload a CSV file. The CSVtoJSONFunction() [please refer below code] converts the CSV to JSON.
So far I am able to output the content of the CSV file as a JSON in the webpage and also post it another page.

Here is the code I have

```js
function ReadCSVFunction(file, delimiter, callback) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  // after the file reader had loaded the file
  reader.onload = function() {
    callback(this.result);
  }
  // Read the file content as a single string
  reader.readAsText(file);
}

//var csv is the CSV file with headers
function CSVtoJSONFunction(csv) {
  //Split string at new line charecters
  //new line charecter may vary
  var lines = csv.split("\r\n");
  //convert string to JSON
  var result = [];
  var headers = lines[0].split(",");
  for (var i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
    var obj = {};
    var currentline = lines[i].split(",");
    for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
      obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
    }
    result.push(obj);

  }
  //Write JSON to hideen input and submit form
  document.getElementById("userdata").value = JSON.stringify(result);
  document.myform.submit();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result); //holds the JSON
}

//add listner to input file
document.querySelector('input[type="file"]')
  .addEventListener('change', function() {
    var files = this.files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      ReadCSVFunction(files[i], ',', function(result) {
        var ans = CSVtoJSONFunction(result.toString());
      });
    }
  });
```

```html
<h2>
  Upload your CSV file
</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<input type="file">
<!--Change the action attribute to the cloud page where your insert logic exists -->

<br><br>
<form name="myform" action="URL_OF_2ND_PAGE" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" id="userdata" value="" name="userdata">
</form>
```

**SSJS(Server Side Java Script) code on Page 2**

```
   <h1>
  Your data has been imported successfully
</h1>
%%[
    /*Declare Variables*/
    var @userdata
    /*Get JSON  from url*/
    Set @userdata = RequestParameter("userdata")
]%%
       <script runat="server">
          Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
          try{
            //Get JSON string retrived by AMPscript from URL parameter
            var userdata= Variable.GetValue("@userdata");
            //parse JSON
            var users = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(userdata)
            //Loop through JSON aray and insert every single user into DE
            var userarray=[];
            for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
              //get single user
              var user = users[i];
              //Create user array for insert function
              //Change the attributes as per headers in your file
              userarray.push(user['First Name']);
              userarray.push(user['Last Name']);
              userarray.push(user['Email']);
              userarray.length=0;
            }
          }
          //end try
          catch(e){
            Write(Stringify(e));
          }
          //End catch
        </script>
```

**Problem**
When I post small amount of data (say between 1 rows to 5000 rows) I can easily post and access this data in 2nd page. But When I have a lot of row say 100k then I am not able to post this data and I the page fails. Is there a way to post a large data to another page or a workaround for this?

Comment: So I assume you are using some sort of backend to process it? What is the serverside language? What is the error you are seeing? Is there a reason you are not just processing the CSV on the server?

Comment: I am using Server Side Java Script (SSJS) - running in Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

Comment: This SSJS runs before Client side javascript(csjs) and hence I am using 2 different webpages

Comment: I get 500 error

Comment: I have edited my answer and added the server side code as well. Thank you